# Show loading animation while module lazy loads?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my main routes I have my profile module lazy loaded on `/profile` like so:

```
  {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
      path: 'profile', loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
  },
  {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: '',
      pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

However, my profile module takes ~1.5 - 2 seconds to load which is quite slow. I'd like to show some sort of loading animation while my module loads, is there anyway to do so? I tried doing this:

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- other stuff ... -->

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="loading">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and inside my css, I had:

```
  /* default .loading styles, .loading should be invisible, opacity: 0, z-index: -1 */
  .loading {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #1B1B1B;
      color: white;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  /* .loading screen is visible when app is not bootstraped yet, .my-app is empty */
  router-outlet:empty + .loading,
  router-outlet:empty + .spinner {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 100;
  }  

  /* spinner animation css stuff */
```

But this doesn't seem to work, Is there anyway to show some loader while angular2 modules are loaded?

Answer (score 2):

router-outlet wont put stuff inside itself , it would put it next to it.

When it's empty :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So , when it's loaded , it would be :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<your-code></your-code> // which is loaded afterward
```

So ***router-outlet:empty*** shouldn't do anything.

You can say :

```
  router-outlet + .loading .spinner {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 100;
  }
```

Comment: appreciate the answer, however I could not get any sort of loading working using the `.loader` and `.spinner`

Comment: @SyntacticFructose , I updated my answer , but generally , you should first make sure your animation is working and then try to integrate it with router stuff